# Selects all elements with a specific data attribute and equalizes their heights

Tags: javascript

This script looks for a data attribute applied to elements within a specified wrapper.
It then sets all elements with the attribute to the same height (height of tallest div).
I needed to add a wait time as the script would sometimes get the heights of the divs before the page had fully rendered. Even though the await is set to 0, it works.

There is also an event listener to listen for resize, and adjust the elements as they change size.

I have only been coding JS for a few weeks so I am not great at it.

#### HTML

```
<div id="div1">
  <div data-equalize>
    <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
  <div data-equalize>
    <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
  <div data-equalize>
    <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
  <div data-equalize>
    <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Script

```
function equalizer(wrap) {
  const equalizeEls = Array.from(wrap.querySelectorAll(`[data-equalize]`));
  const wait = (ms = 0) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

  //get the largest height in the array
  function getLargestNumber(arr) {
    return Math.max(...arr);
  }

  //get an array of heights
  function getTallest(arr) {
    const allheights = arr.map(x => x.clientHeight);
    return getLargestNumber(allheights)  
  }

  function equalizeHeights(els) {
    const largest = getTallest(els);
    return els.forEach(el => {
       el.style.minHeight = `${largest}px`
    });
  }

  async function handleResize() {
    await wait(0); //needs a await to ensure page is fully loaded 
    equalizeHeights(equalizeEls)
  }

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handleResize);
  window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
}
```

#### Running the script

```
new equalizer(document.querySelector(`#div1`))
```

Comment: Are the divs positioned side by side? Then this can be done with CSS alone using flex or grid layout.

Comment: Not always, I use flexbox when I can though.

Answer (score 3):

## data attribute

It's a bit unconventional to use a data attribute to select the affected elements. A class would be the more conventional approach.

## Use of template strings

You have two places where you unnecessarily use template strings with backticks (`` ` ``).

## Code

I like the code overall very much. Nice break down into functions. Nice use of modern JS features.

Only one small thing: The `return` in `equalizeHeights` is unnecessary.

## Timing

The problem with the need for the wait may be due to contents of the divs. If they contain images or use external fonts, then they may lead to resizing of the divs while these are loading. Some points to look out for:

- Use the `load` event instead or additionally to `DOMContentLoaded`.
- Make sure images have a size assigned to them, either in the HTML (`height` and `width` attributes) or the CSS.
- There a ways to make sure that the text content isn't rendered until the fonts are loaded, but this is not really my area of expertise.

## Possible bug/misfeature

There is one problem with the script: It never allows the divs to shrink if the content becomes shorter, for example due to a window resize.

I can think of two possible solutions:

- Before checking the size of the divs, remove the `min-height`s and `wait()` to allow a re-render.

Or

- add a second, inner div inside the equalize divs and use the inner divs client height to determine the largest div.